# Creating a new list from an old list (R)

Tags: r, list, for-loop, if-statement, append

As a python user, R has been somewhat intuitive thus far. However, I'm running into a problem with creating a new list from an old one.

Specifically I have a list:

```
> x
[[1]]
  [1] "Heads" "Tails" "Tails" "Heads" "Tails" "Heads"
  [7] "Tails" "Tails" "Tails" "Heads" "Heads" "Tails"
  ... .... ... etc.
```

This is length 100. I'd like to loop through this list and create a list y with the values 'Heads' = 1, 'Tails' = -1. My attempt so far:

```
> for (val in x) {
         ifelse(val == 'Heads', c(y,1), c(y,-1))}
```

Which appends an empty list y. However, the result is a list of length 2. Can anybody help me here?

Comment: You want a new list of two columns with the first one having the ``Heads`` and ``Tails`` value and the second column having ``1`` and ``-1`` respectively?

Comment: Can you make your example input reproducible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the output of length(x) and lengths(x) ?

Comment: You need to save the results of `ifelse` to something. Probably `y`... `y <- ifelse(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named vector:

```
c("Heads" = 1, "Tails" = -1)[x[[1]]]
> Heads Tails Tails Heads Tails Heads Tails Tails Tails Heads Heads Tails 
      1    -1    -1     1    -1     1    -1    -1    -1     1     1    -1
```

Or to get a vector using boolean conversion to numeric (elegant but maybe not the most efficient):

```
(x[[1]] == "Heads") * 2 - 1
> [1]  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1
```

Comment: The second solution is exactly what I was looking for: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have a nested list with two unique values. You can use `lapply` for that:

```
x <- list(list("Heads","Tails","Heads"),list("Heads","Tails","Tails"))
lapply(x, function(x){y <- ifelse(x == "Heads", 1, -1); names(y) <- x; y})

# [[1]]
# Heads Tails Heads 
# 1    -1     1 
# 
# [[2]]
# Heads Tails Tails 
# 1    -1    -1
```

or, if you don't need the names, use `rapply`:

```
x <- list(list("Heads","Tails","Heads"),list("Heads","Tails","Tails"))
rapply(x, function(x){ifelse(x == "Heads", 1, -1)})
```